# which test is used to find relation for a categorical variable between two groups?

Tags: r, inference, descriptive-statistics

i have a categorical variable lets say  variable "sex" : levels (Male,Female)
 and data is divided into two groups "treated" and "not treated". which test used to find correlation for a categorical variable("sex") between two groups?

i am thinking "chi square test for independence" can be used in this case to find p.value(correlation) between two groups  but not sure whether it is  right or wrong.

Answer (score 1):

If you are performing a chi-square test of independence you could use Cramér's phi to evaluate the strength of the dependency.